# jQuery access parent object attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
function theObject(){
    this.someelement = $("#someelement");
    this.someotherelement = $("someotherelement");
    this.someelement.fadeOut(500, function(){
       this.someotherelement.attr("title", "something");
       this.someelement.fadeIn(500); 
    });
}
```

for some reason `this.someotherelement` is undefined. I'm guessing because it's wrapped in a `function(){}`?

Comment: Is that the id of the element? You are missing a # sign.

Comment: post some of the relevant html too, so it will be more clear...

Comment: Inside the function, `this` refers to `this.someelement` (actually to its DOM element). With most (every?) jQuery function that takes a callback, `this` refers to the (DOM) element you call the function on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a JavaScript scoping issue. Creating a function creates a new scope for `this` which makes `this` refer to the function. You can fix it by doing ... this:

```
function theObject(){
  this.someelement = $("#someelement");
  this.someotherelement = $("someotherelement");

  // bind this to that (what?). This way, this will still be accessible inside
  // the new function's scope as that
  var that = this;
  this.someelement.fadeOut(500, function(){
    that.someotherelement.attr("title", "something");
    that.someelement.fadeIn(500); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function `this` means something else. You could capture it though:

```
this.someotherelement = $("someotherelement");
var _this = this;
this.someelement.fadeOut(500, function(){
   _this.someotherelement.attr("title", "something");
   _this.someelement.fadeIn(500); 
});
```

Comment: Instead of `_this.someelement` you could also use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code , I hope it helps.

```
function theObject(){
    var someelement = $("#someelement");
    var someotherelement = $("#someotherelement");
    someelement.fadeOut(500, function(){
       someotherelement.attr("title", "something");
       someelement.fadeIn(500); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is someotherelement an ID? If so, you are missing a #...

```
this.someotherelement = $("#someotherelement");
```